# Interface declaration location in IDL files

Tags: c#, com, managed, idl

I'm working on a project that's upgrading a (*very*) old (and considerably large) program written extensively with COM / MFC to using WPF / managed .NET components, and part of it is trying to port over old COM interfaces declared in IDLs to managed C# interfaces.  What's the difference between interfaces declared inside and outside 'library' blocks ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one.  Declaring an interface inside `library {}` just ensures it is present in the type library even if it isn't referenced by any coclasses.  Nothing that matters to your C# declarations.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was hoping for.  Thank you.